# Get daemon status programmatically on macOS using Qt

Tags: macos, qt, daemons

I need to query my daemon status from system tray application using Qt. Can't find any solution to do that.

For the Windows part I can use Win32 API: OpenSCManager -> OpenService -> QueryServiceStatus/QueryServiceStatusEx. Need the way to do the same for Mac.

The daemon's plist located in LaunchAgents, loaded with launchctl load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable, disable and start services programmatically in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607232/enable-disable-and-start-services-programmatically-in-macos)

Comment: It's similar, but not the same. My question is about Qt, not the objective-C.

Comment: but if system do not exposes functionality (any more) then Qt or Objective C no difference.

Comment: So, that mean no way to implement daemon interaction?